# 'An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers' on Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm trying to send a message to a topic with FCM in a Firebase Cloud Function triggered when a Firestore document (a message) is created. Subscribing to the topic (also done with Functions) and triggering the send function works fine, but the actual send fails with:

```
Error: An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for setup instructions.
```

and some raw HTML containing `<H1>PROJECT_NOT_PERMITTED</H1>` and `<H1>PROJECT_NOT_PERMITTED</H1>` .

Here is my code (index.ts):

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
});

export * from './messages';
```

and (messages.ts):

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const publishMessage = functions
  .firestore.document('/messages/{messageId}').onCreate(
    (snapshot, context) => {
      const data = snapshot.data();
      const message = {
        notification: {
          title: `${data.sentBy} sent a message`,
          body: data.message,
        },
      };

      return admin.messaging().sendToTopic('messages', message);
    },
  );
```

According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#provide-credentials-using-adc this should work. I have also tried doing it without any parameters (https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-without-parameters) but it fails all the same. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using an active `service account`?

Comment: As far as I know I do. This is a brand new Firebase project and a service account for it is created. When I go to Google Cloud Console to IAM & Admin -> Service Accounts I see two: firebase-adminsdk-xxxxx@<projectId>.iam.gserviceaccount.com and  <projectId>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com and both are enabled. Neither of them has any keyss but this should not be necessary, right?

Comment: Yes, it should not matter, what's important is the roles that is included in your `<projectId>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`. I've posted an answer to further discuss this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that instead of this

```js
      const message = {
        notification: {
          title: `${data.sentBy} sent a message`,
          body: data.message,
        },
      };

      return admin.messaging().sendToTopic('messages', message);
```

I needed this:

```js
      const message = {
        notification: {
          title: `${data.sentBy} sent a message`,
          body: data.message,
        },
        topic: 'messages',
      };

      return admin.messaging().send('messages', message);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do enable Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) in Project settings/Cloud Messaging

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElwpB.png

Comment: Thanks, this will also fix the issue I'm having, although I prefer not to start the project with a legacy FCM setup. See my own answer how to change the code for it work properly.

Answer (score 2):

This is because Google Firebase versions changed and `admin.messaging().sendToDevice()` no longer works out of the box.

Now following works well:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require('./xxx.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

const registrationToken = 'fKuD...';

const message = {
  token: registrationToken,
  notification: {
    title: "FCM IS COOL !",
    body: "Notification has been recieved",
    imageUrl: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iosNuIdQoy8/maxresdefault.jpg"
  }
}

admin.messaging().send(message);
```

Note `databaseURL` in firebase-admin is no longer needed. Just private key you download in Firebase Console.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, enabling API solved the issue. Seems like by default only
`Firebase Cloud Messaging` API is enabled but `Cloud Messaging` API is not enabled. You need to enable that one from [APIs page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library) and it will solve the issue

Comment: How this is a thing I don't know but it definitely works

Answer (score 1):

After removing the (`roles/firebase.admin`) in my `<projectId>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`, I also encountered your error:

[image]

Since the `<projectId>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` service account is being used by Firebase Cloud Functions. Roles and permissions added to this service account carry over to the Cloud Functions runtime.

As you've already stated, you have `<projectId>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`, make sure that it has a (`roles/firebase.admin`), and according to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#firebase-roles), it has a full access for `cloudmessaging.*` permission.

After I re-added the `<projectId>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` and the correspoding (`roles/firebase.admin`):

[image]

I've tried adding another Firestore document to test the function (after 10 minutes or so) just to make sure that the changes in my permissions have taken effect:

[image]

For other options, you can also try to add the:

1. **Firebase Grow Admin** (`roles/firebase.growthAdmin`);
2. Or you can try the beta of **Firebase Cloud Messaging API Admin** (`roles/firebasecloudmessaging.admin`) since it also has `cloudmessaging.*` permission.

You can also check the [other roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#other-roles) with it's corresponding permissions.

Comment: I added the role to both accounts and nothing changed. I also don't understand why I would need to do this as I never disabled or deleted anything, I have a fresh Firebase project.

Comment: I've updated my answer and provided screenshots, and the steps I've done in order to replicate your error and find a solution.

Comment: I retested it and also waited about 20 minutes (didn't wait in my previous test) but it doesn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Since my proposed solution didn't resolve your issue, you can file a support ticket directly to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support).